# SharePoint web page title alignment issue

Tags: publishing-site, navigation

I am using SharePoint 2007 + Windows Server 2008 with SharePoint 2007's publishing portal template. When I add a new web page, the title will aligned on the left, any ideas to align the title in the center?

[image]

Solid line means current title position, dashed line means the position I want the title to place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change the Layout Page to get what you want.
Reason why it always aligns to the left is that it is defined so in the Layout page.

There are two possible options for you to change this.

1. Open the SharePoint Designer , open the Layout page that you are using and change the alignment of the FieldControl of the Title Column.
2. Create a new layout page with the aligment of the title field control and deploy it as the Feature.

In both the case while editing page TextBox that accepts the Value will also be aligned to Right. That too can be corrected if you need.

Comment: "open the Layout page that you are using and change the alignment of the FieldControl of the Title Column." -- I am interested in this, but I have never edited layout page before. Could you let me know how to find the layout page I am using please?

Comment: @George2: Unless you need a quick verification on something, it would be much better to ask a brand new question! It makes it easier for others to find that need similar help. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I am wondering whether the layout you mean master page? I need to make it clear before I ask a new question. :-)

Comment: @George2: Its PageLayout.

Comment: Hi Kusek, I am a little bit confused. Do you mean the PageLayoutTemplate.aspx? Here is my screen snapshot. http://i38.tinypic.com/2nleern.png

Comment: @George2: PageLayoutTemplate.aspx is something different.I am unsure what is the layout page your Page is based on. You can find it by navigating to the location where abc1.aspx resides and say edit.SharePoint designer will prompt to if you want to edit the Page Layout instead, by that way you can get to know the Page Layout Name. You edit the page , check-in and Approve the changes to see in your site.